Use YOLO with unbounded input exported to an mlpackage/mlmodel file
I want to create an .mlpackage or .mlmodel file which I can import in Xcode to do image segmentation. For this, I want to use the segmentation package within YOLO to check out if it fit my needs.
The problem now is that this script creates an .mlpackage file which only accepts images with a fixed size (640x640):
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO("yolo11n-seg.pt")

model.export(format="coreml")

I want the change something here, probably with coremltools, to handle unbounded ranges (I want to handle arbitrary sized images). It's described a bit here: https://apple.github.io/coremltools/docs-guides/source/flexible-inputs.html#enable-unbounded-ranges, but I don't understand how I can implement it with my script.

Wouldn't you simply resize the image to match the network dimensions?  I'm not familiar with the tools you're asking about since I manage the Darknet/YOLO codebase not Ultralytics nor Mac-specific tools, but normally you don't have to worry (too much) about the image size.  Simply resize the image before passing it to the framework for inference.

@Stéphane I want to make a simple image editor where I can identify objects. The tricky part is that users should be able to upload any image they want of any size. If  I have to resize the image to 640x640, the quality of the image will decrease drastically (because it's a pretty small imagesize).

And yet, that's how it works. Resize a temporary copy, run detection, and then scale the coordinates back to match your original image dimensions.  None of what you said changes the fact that inference happens on an image that must match the network dimensions.
